# VBA copying worksheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I know this question is discussed many times and I have checked almost all sources but I don't know why this simple code does not work. I want to copy a worksheet from one workbook to another.

```
Sub SimpleCode()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks("C:\Users\File1.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("C:\Users\File2.xlsx")

wb1.Sheets("File1Sheet1").Copy After:=wb2.Sheets("File2Sheet1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the workbooks? (`Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\File1.xlsx"`

Comment: What does it do *instead* of working?  If the workbooks are open then you only use the file *name* (not the full path) to reference them.  If they aren't open then as @cybernetic.nomad notes you will need to open them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both files are open you only need to call the name of the workbooks, not the full name:

```
Sub SimpleCode()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks("File1.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("File2.xlsx")

wb1.Sheets("File1Sheet1").Copy After:=wb2.Sheets("File2Sheet1")

End Sub
```

Comment: @StackUser if this answered your question please hit the checkmark at the upper left of the post